# Simple javascript conditional not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

Sorry to bother you. I'm having some trouble with a simple javascript if... else statement.

I have a button, if you click it once it pushes `#everythingelse` to the left. If you click it again, it is supposed to bring `#everythingelse` back to the original position but it does nothing on the second click.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var inout = "0";
$("#mobilemenubutton").click(function () {
    if (inout = "0") {
        $("#everythingelse").animate({
            left: '70%'
        }, 500);
        var inout = "1";
    } else {
        $("#everythingelse").animate({
            left: '0%'
        }, 500);
        var inout = "0";
    }
});         
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changed you code as, in the if statement you need to be using double == which means is this equal that.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    var inout="0";
    $("#mobilemenubutton").click(function () {
        if(inout=="0"){
            $("#everythingelse").animate({ left: '70%' }, 500);
            inout="1"; // removed "var"
        }else{
            $("#everythingelse").animate({ left: '0%' }, 500);
            inout="0"; // removed "var"
        }
    });     
    </script>
```

But I would suggest you to go for this. You can use jQuery's [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to keep track of the state instead of variable.

```
$('#mobilemenubutton').on('click', function(){
    $("#everythingelse").animate({ left : !$(this).data('state') ? '70%' : '0%' }, 500);
    $("#everythingelse").data('state', !$(this).data('state'));
});
```

Comment: Can't believe it was something as simple as using '==' instead of '=' (even I should have caught that one). For some reason the jQuery didn't work for me but the other piece of code works just fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` statement is using `=` instead of `==` for comparison. The way you have it currently would set `inout` to `"0"` every time.

You are also defining the `inout` variable again twice inside the `if` statement using `var`.

Try this (see comments for changes):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var inout="0";
    $("#mobilemenubutton").click(function () {
        if(inout=="0"){ //changed '=' to '=='
            $("#everythingelse").animate({ left: '70%' }, 500);
            inout="1"; //removed 'var'
        }else{
            $("#everythingelse").animate({ left: '0%' }, 500);
            inout="0"; //removed 'var'
        }
    });      
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your if is wrong. Everytime when you run the code you set it to 0
`if(inout="0")` should be `if(inout=="0")` or even better `if(inout==="0")`

also remove `var` inside the function